# What does "F.P." mean in a 1930s cocktail recipe?

Tags: sens, traduction, histoire

I would like to make some of the cocktails described in [this wine merchant's brochure from 1934.](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k9324070/f5.item)

But I don't know what "F.P." means in the given cocktail recipes and I can not devise a search term which gives me useful results.

I suspect, from the context, that it means something like "Your Preferred Brand".

**What does "F.P." mean?**

Here's an example (the link above is to a scanned document, hence not not easily copied):

**

### Port Whine Cocktail

**
Dans un verre à mélange; mettre quelques morceaux de glace - 3 traits de Bitter - 2 traits de Curaçao F.P. - Finir avec Porto Rouge F.P. - Remuer et passer dans un verre à Madère - Servir avec un zeste de citron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [Félix Potin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A9lix_Potin), famous for its motto, ***Félix Potin, on y revient***. See [the French Godfather of Modern Grocery Stores](https://france-amerique.com/en/felix-potin-the-french-godfather-of-modern-grocery-stores/)

Comment: « Confirmé » en plus à la [p. précédente](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k9324070/f4.item).